# Removing a querystring in PHP and reloading the page

Tags: php, query-string

Whats the best way in PHP to reload the page I'm on with all the previous query string values removed from the URL?

Comment: `header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");` or `header("Location: ?");`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: But that won't remove the query string...

Comment: @Horen I edited it as you posted your comment, but yes it would. `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` doesn't include the query string and would redirect to the same page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take off the params with [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function:

```
$url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)
```

And then use [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) redirect with PHP:

```
//it there is any parameter...
if(count($_GET)) {
    header('Location: '.$url);
    die();
}
```

You have to make use of the `header` function before generating any output. 
Also, you should locate the `header` inside some kind of condition to avoid redirecting in any other cases.

Comment: If this is being run at the top of the same page, how will you prevent infinite redirect loop?

Comment: Making use of any condition.

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise `if(!empty($_GET))header(...)`

Comment: @Steve: I meant that should really be part of your answer.

Comment: Always `die()` after a redirect, unless you _really_ want the page to continue execution.